# Passing a Parameter in Oracle Using SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server-2012, oracle-sqldeveloper, ssrs-2012

This is my Query In SSRS Report:

```
SELECT
  GTCODE,
  COUNT(GTCODE),
  SUM(HLD_FLG),
  Reason
FROM ICWGHC.W_STOCKINFO
WHERE GTCODE IN (?GTC)
GROUP BY GTCODE, Reason;
```

I have Connected SSRS to ORACLE through ODBC.
I have to pass the parameter GTC, I have created another Dataset for the parameter.

And when i execute the query i get this message

> ERROR ORA 00907 missing right parenthesis

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For ODBC data sources, no need to specify the parameter name after the question mark. You can use

```
SELECT
  GTCODE,
  COUNT(GTCODE),
  SUM(HLD_FLG),
  Reason
FROM ICWGHC.W_STOCKINFO
WHERE GTCODE IN (?)
GROUP BY GTCODE, Reason;
```

After editing the query go to the parameters tab to correctly map the parameter. Replace the Parameter value with (assuming your parameter name is GTC):

```
=Join(Parameters!GTC.Value,",")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked well but i cannot pass multiple parameters in it

Comment: how about multiple parameter ?